# Translate from Objective-C to Swift (TestFlight)

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, swift

Does anybody know how to translate from Objective-C to Swift from this line from TestFlight? I am trying to figure out how to translate it.  Any suggestion appreciated.

```
//Objective-C
[TestFlight setOptions:@{ @"TFOptionDisableInAppUpdates" : @YES }];

//Swift
TestFlight.setOptions.........
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

without xcode / trying it

swift would be:
`TestFlight.setOptions( ["TFOptionDisableInAppUpdates": true] )`